# How can I serialize a class with an attribute

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a class that has

```
[XmlRoot]
<snip>

[XmlAttribute(AttributeName="x:uid")]
public string uid;

<snip>
```

It is OK At compile time.. however at runtime,
exception occurs at line

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myClass));
```

because of the invalid character in "x:uid"..
The element in my class needs to have an "x:uid" attribute for localization purposes..
How can I do that??

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

To set the namespace of the attribute, you'll need to use the [`Namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.namespace.aspx) property of `XmlAttributeAttribute`.

If it's particularly important that the prefix used for that namespace is "x" then you can control this using the [`XmlSerializerNamespaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializernamespaces.aspx) class when doing serialization, optionally with [`XmlNamespaceDeclarationsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlnamespacedeclarationsattribute.aspx).

---

Here's a working example:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://foo")]
public class MyClass
{
    private XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns;

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces Xmlns 
    {
        get
        {
            if (xmlns == null)
            {
                xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                xmlns.Add("x", "http://xxx");
            }
            return xmlns;
        }
        set { xmlns = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute("uid", Namespace = "http://xxx")]
    public int Uid { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        s.Serialize(Console.Out, new MyClass { Uid = 123 });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Which produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<MyClass 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:x="http://xxx" 
    x:uid="123" 
    xmlns="http://foo"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the actual namespace - not the alias (which the writer will decide):

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName="uid", Namespace="http://my/full/namespace")]
public string uid;
```

Note that it is common to use a "`const string`" for the namespaces, etc. Also, public fields not a good idea - with C# 3.0 you could have (xml attributes not shown):

```
public string Uid {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot use the namespace prefix in the C# XML attribute declaration. Try just "uid" without "x:"

Comment: XML attributes *can* have namespaces.