# Adding a namespace prefix to an XmlRoot Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

:riI am working on a .Net web api, we have a base class that handles all responses from our api. This class will always be returned as the root of the request, with whatever data the user requested inside it.

So the user will always receive a response along the lines of:

```
<Content xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/TestNamespace/Interface6/Schema.xsd">
        <Item>Information Here</Item>
</Content>
```

I have the following code which returns the above fine:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Content", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/schemas/TestNamespace/Interface6/Schema.xsd")]
public class MyResponse<T> : IMyResponse<T>
    where T : class
{//rest of class}
```

So no matter what the root tag of the return data is, it will always be changed to "Content". So if T in my code is a PersonList, itll be changed to "Content" in the XML. This is to provide consistency in our responses.

Now I need to add a prefix to the tag. "ri:" So the response received will be:

```
<ri:Content xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:ri="http://www.example.com/schemas/TestNamespace/Interface6/Schema.xsd">
        <Item>Information Here</Item>
</ri:Content>
```

Every question close to what i require has provided solutions to add the prefix in code.

I want to know if there is a way to do this using the attribute ?

[Here is a similar question that was never answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122557/how-to-add-prefix-in-front-of-xml-element-using-attribute-in-c-sharp)

Edit: Adding ri: to the ElementName of the XmlRoot Attribute does not work.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ri:Content", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/schemas/TestNamespace/Interface6/Schema.xsd")]
```

Returns as:

```
<ri_x003A_Content xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://www.example.com/schemas/TestNamespace/Interface6/Schema.xsd">
            <Item>Information Here</Item>
    </ri_x003A_Content>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I completely forgot to add it in. Edited my post. `xmlns:ri="http://www.example.com/schemas/TestNamespace/Interface6/Schema.xsd"` is what should be there.

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to perform serialization to XML?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782/xml-serialization-and-namespace-prefixes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is **no, you currently can't add namespace prefixes via XML serialization attributes.**

The attributes describe only the *structure* of the XML document. Namespace prefixes are largely irrelevant to an XML DOM - all that matters is that the element has the correct namespace. The prefix is only interesting to the text representation of that document, which is entirely a *formatting* concern and is outside the scope of the serialization attributes purpose.

If you need to control the format of the XML text being written, you need to take control of the formatting process, which requires you modify the code which performs the serialization.

See [XML Serialization and namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339782) for a really simple example of how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do it such a way:

```
var serializerNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
serializerNamespaces.Add("ri", http://www.example.com/schemas/TestNamespace/Interface6/Schema.xsd");
```

then

```
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Content ", Namespace = "http://www.example.com/schemas/TestNamespace/Interface6/Schema.xsd")]
    class MyResponse<T> : IMyResponse<T>
    where T : class
```

and then do your Serialize including XmlSerializerNamespaces as argument:

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
 serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, object, serializerNamespaces);
```